Need very flat surface without breaking the bank
I'm not an engineer but I really need a very flat surface that doesn't cost too much urgently. In trying to realign my guitar neck and suspect that it is slightly twisted too. Since I'm a perfectionist I really want to dial it in to at least a tenth of a millimeter. For that however I need a long reference plane that isn't too expensive. Would an acrylic glass plate be suitable? Any suggestions?
Edit: I am somewhat experienced in setting up guitars so I don't need help to properly set up a guitar. I just need a good reference plane for some things I build that doesn't require millionth of a millimeter precision.

Do you mean "flat" rather than "that"?  Could you edit the subject, please?

If you just need to borrow one, or to try something out, check with the local golf course for a reel-squaring bench plate. They cost about 500 bucks and are about the right size. https://accuproducts.com/product/bench-plate/

Acrylic is one material (plastic, not glass), although not what I would recommend, too much flexibility. Glass is another material and is going to be suitable, especially if you can find a suitably sized mirror. Mirrors have to be as flat as possible to avoid visual distortions and it's common in my area to see them near the street for rubbish collection, or inexpensively at yard sales.

a mirror has a bit of flex

Yes, it can, but if well supported, that's out of the picture, so to speak, and also easily determined visually.

Thanks that's a great idea. I knew about glass plates but someone told me that unless it is a certified flat surface it wouldn't be too much of a help. I need it so I can make certain measurements. I need a perfectly flat surface as a reference point. I will try if I can find a mirror that I can support on a workbench so it doesn't flex. Acrylic flexes but I have seen people use that too but they usually used very thick plates to avoid flex.

If you wish to ensure the best results with a mirror, create a grid on paper of a suitable size and with perhaps 10-15 mm squares, but make certain it is precise. Observe the reflection as you move the mirror. You'll see distortions (and lack thereof). You can perform this with the mirror standing vertically and probably get good results, as the gravity will not create any flex, if you get the mirror as vertical as possible.

Well I have to put the mirror on the ground though. It's of no use in the vertical position. I need it to measure the height of certain points.

Followed your advice and was able to get a really nice flat neck heel. Thanks a lot man. If anyone could give my question an upvote that would be nice. I'm new here.

I'm glad things worked out. As you are the original posting party, you can select the check mark under my up/down votes and mark this as accepted.

You can buy fret-levelling sander blocks that are ground flat to a thou or so long enough to cover all the frets. This is how the problem is solved if you do not have access to a CNC milling machine.
How to find a cheap flat table? try a pool table. In a college town, they are sometimes given away at the end of the school year. You would automatically be the coolest guitar repair guy in town if you had a pool table as a flat bench!

No it isn't. If you start with a perfectly flat neck the less you have to compensate by leveling frets. You shouldn't use the frets to compensate for a twisted neck anyways since twists can't be compensated that way. I am familiar with setting up guitars no need to explain. So can please somebody answer me what I could use as a very flat suface to do some measurement? Is a well supported mirror suitable? Acrylic plates? I wanted suggestions concerning that not how to set up my neck. I know that.

You can buy precision-ground (flat) cast aluminum tooling plate in thicknesses of up to an inch. Much stiffer than a mirror blank. Personally I would knurl the backside of the plate, degrease it, and epoxy it to a slab of very thick furniture-grade particleboard. For highest precision I would take that assembly to a machine shop and have it ground dead flat after the epoxy sets up. That said, I have several friends who bought or were given optical bench platforms (we're talking FLAT here) studded with threaded holes in a grid pattern for affixing components, lasers, lenses, etc. , more...

-for some reason, the biggest flat tables are almost worthless on the used market perhaps because of their cumbersomeness. Same for flat granite tool setup and calibration slabs. Or how about a derelict pool table? those suckers are flat and in a college town they often turn up as end-of-semester giveaways. I think it would be totally cool to convert a pool table into a luthier's setup bench- if you've got the space! Best regards, Niels

Niels! That is a great idea!!! Thanks man! I mean I don't need millionth of an inch precision especially not with wood that is constantly changing dimensions. But I would like to have something that is reasonably flat to also measure other things not just my instruments dimensions. Are they really that flat though? I would have to pull off the cloth from the table right? I will take a look if I find someone giving a used old one away maybe.

You go, man!!! -NN

I looked it up. Apparently pool tables are quite flat but can have up to half a millimeter of deviation from absolute level. Depends on the model. But they usually use slate rock (I don't know if that is the correct term) and I think using a dial gauge which I can get for around 50 bucks should give me something to determine its flatness. Thanks for the great idea man. You should write a real answer to my question I will definitely give you an upvote.

It depends upon how flat you want and how much variation you can accept over the  distance being measured.  For each extra decimal, expect to pay another 10X as much.  You say 0.1 mm.  For that (as observed by @fred_dot_u), a nice mirror, say made of 1/4 inch plate glass, if supported should do what you need.
I have a big steel surface on my saw table that I use for such purposes.  It is not certifiably flat but it is "close."  If I put straight edge on it, it is off about the thickness of about 0.5mm over a distance of 24".
You can buy a Granite Surface Plate on Amazon that is good within ±.0003" which is a bit more than you need.  If you really want to break the bank, a place I worked a while ago had a Starrett Granite Surface Plate (like this one) that was good for 0.000100". They were doing super-industrial, precision type stuff that required that everything be calibrated and tracible.

I have a surface plate, relatively small, perhaps 0.5 m on a side, with I think Class B certification. Certainly overkill for the OP and almost certainly more expensive than a cast-away or yard sale mirror. I'm a scrounger and always glad to grab a bargain. I have seen at least three qualifying mirrors on the curb over the last two weeks, so it's an easy pick.

No I don't want to break the bank. I said as much in my original question. I know I don't need something super precides since wood is an inherently unstable material. But I need a good starting point.

Aaah, come on.  Where is your sense of adventure?  Why not blow $3000 on a super precise thing you will use exactly once (and don't really need it even then)?  Just think of the pride of ownership.  A machine shop near my office was auctioning off one we figured weighed a bit over 1000 pounds.  I looked at it and as obsessed as I am with tools and precision, I had to pass.
“No.”
“But it’s good for 0.00005 inches”
“Still No”
I believe they had to take the office apart to get the forklift in to move it for the new owner.
